# Return to a previously loaded page and show a popup

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a page that displays a summary of open sales calls.  When a user clicks on on of the summaries, an ajax call is made that shows the selected call in full detail.  Here the user can make changes to the call and click save.  When save is clicked, another ajax call is made to write the data to the database.

What I would like to do is this.. if the save is successful, return to the original page that shows the summaries and fire a popup that says the save was successful.  The problem I am having is getting the popup to not fire when the page is initially loaded, or if the 'return without saving' button is clicked.

The pages are using php and javascript, with ajax calls.

I hope this makes a little bit of sense.  Thanks for any pointers you all may have.

Comment: where is the code where you have the problem ?

Comment: Why not just set a $_SESSION variable in the ajax response, echo it at the original page if it's set and unset it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the save is successful, redirect them to a URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/previousPage.php?result=success
```

Then, in the code for previousPage.php, just have something like:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['result']) && $_GET['result'] == 'success')
{
    echo '<script>alert("Success!");</script>';
}

?>
```

Comment: This worked great.  I thought I had tried this idea once before with no luck, but I guess not.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you be using ajax to get the sales call, then changing the page?
I would suggest using a modal dialogue to show your selected call, using something like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form). Then the user never leaves the current page.

Comment: This is actually for a mobile app that was already created, I am just adding this part on.  It is already full of ajax.  It wouldn't have been my first choice either!